# How do I run multiple NUnit test projects in one Jenkins Item?

Tags: c#, jenkins, continuous-integration, nunit

What I'm looking for, is to be able to build multiple Visual Studio projects from the same solution and have the output of these tests go to the same test report XML file. The closest I've gotten to make it work was running 3 batch commands, like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe"  Project1.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\Project1.Test.Unit.dll --result:UnitTestResult.xml

"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe"  Project2.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\Project2.Test.Unit.dll --result:UnitTestResult.xml

"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe"  Project3.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\Project3.Test.Unit.dll --result:UnitTestResult.xml
```

But this seems to cause it to overwrite the UnitTestResult.xml so only the results of the last test project are shown on the chart and in the test results report.

If anyone knows how to do this or if it's even possible, I'd love to hear from them. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add each test project to the NUnit command line. NUnit will run each in parallel in a separate agent process and combine the results into one file.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" --result:UnitTestResult.xml Project1.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\Project1.Test.Unit.dll Project2.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\Project2.Test.Unit.dll Project3.Test.Unit\bin\Debug\Project3.Test.Unit.dll
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't work at first, but I realized that I hadn't enabled parallel builds, so now it does :)